# What is better way to do paging database with Rest api

Tags: database, hibernate, hql

I am trying to list all information of a registered user in table called clients `Clients`

Clients has more than 10000 rows. I want to page it by 50 or 100 with a single API.

In Hibernate HQL `FROM Clients` returns all clients or I can set max and limit number of results.

Currently for API, user wants to work properly total number of clients required.

How can I do it in single **HQL query**

Answer (score 0):

required parameter:

- int page -> page number,
- int recordePerPage -> required record per page, in your case it will
  50 or 100
  @return : null in case of no result, in case of result return list of clint with pagination.

public List getAllClintWithPagination(int page, int recordePerPage) {

```
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tr = null;
        try {
            tr = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Clint.class);
            cr.setFirstResult((page - 1) * recordePerPage);
            cr.setMaxResults(recordePerPage);
            List<Clint> clintAll = cr.list();
            tr.commit();

            if (clintAll.isEmpty()) {
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("clint are not exist");
            }
            return null;
            } else {

            return clintAll;
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            log.error(ex);
            if (tr != null) {
            tr.rollback(); // roll back the transaction due to runtime error
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```